# android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError recyclerview with lots of images

Tags: android, performance, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make an app who will show lots of images. Problem is when I run the app and when I am scrolling, the app crashes and show me error

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

I'm using android studio, minSdkVersion 15 and all pictures are not bigger then 20, 30 KB but I will have lots of images to show. All images are in drawer folder.

This is class where I add all data to objects including images:

```
package com.example.android.animalsoundsforchildren;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Zivotinje {
    private String mAnimal_name;
    private int mAnimal_slika;
    private int mSound;
    private String mkey;

    public Zivotinje(String animalName, int slika, int sound, String key){
        this.setmAnimal_name(animalName);
        this.setmAnimal_slika(slika);
        this.setmSound(sound);
        this.setMkey(key);
    }

    public String getmAnimal_name() {
        return mAnimal_name;
    }

    public void setmAnimal_name(String mAnimal_name) {
        this.mAnimal_name = mAnimal_name;
    }

    public int getmAnimal_slika() {
        return mAnimal_slika;
    }

    public void setmAnimal_slika(int mAnimal_slika) {
        this.mAnimal_slika = mAnimal_slika;
    }
    public int getmSound() {
        return mSound;
    }

    public void setmSound(int mSound) {
        this.mSound = mSound;
    }


    public String getMkey() {
        return mkey;
    }

    public void setMkey(String mkey) {
        this.mkey = mkey;
    }
    //static
    public static ArrayList<Zivotinje> createZivotinjeList(){
        ArrayList<Zivotinje> zivotinje = new ArrayList<Zivotinje>();

        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Sheep", R.drawable.domestic_sheep, R.raw.domestic_sheep, "Domestic"));

        //ADING DATA TO ARRAY OF OBJECTS
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Sparrow", R.drawable.birds_sparrow, R.raw.birds_sparrow, "Birds"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Flamingo", R.drawable.birds_flamingo, R.raw.birds_flamingo, "Birds"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Hyacinth Macaw", R.drawable.birds_hyacinth_macaw, R.raw.birds_hyacinth_macaw, "Birds"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Kestrel", R.drawable.birds_kestrel, R.raw.birds_kestrel, "Birds"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Pigeon", R.drawable.birds_pigeon, R.raw.birds_pigeon, "Birds"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Seagull", R.drawable.birds_seagull, R.raw.birds_seagull, "Birds"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Toucan", R.drawable.birds_toucan, R.raw.birds_toucan, "Birds"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Swallow", R.drawable.birds_swallow, R.raw.birds_swallow, "Birds"));

        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Dolphin", R.drawable.sea_dolphin, R.raw.sea_dolphin, "Sea"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Bumblebee", R.drawable.insects_bumblebee, R.raw.insects_bumblebee, "Insects"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Tractor", R.drawable.cars_tractor, R.raw.cars_tractor, "Cars"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Baby Cry", R.drawable.laugh_baby_cry, R.raw.laugh_baby_cray, "Laugh"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Wind", R.drawable.nature_wind, R.raw.nature_wind, "Nature"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Golf", R.drawable.effects_golf, R.raw.effects_golf, "Effects"));
        zivotinje.add(new Zivotinje("Clock", R.drawable.others_clock, R.raw.others_clock, "Others"));

        return zivotinje;
    }

    //Dohvacamo sve zivotinje i sortiramo specificne po kljucu tako da kad kliknemo recimo others pozove se ovo
    public static ArrayList<Zivotinje> createZivotinjeListPero(String zivotinjeMenu) {
        ArrayList<Zivotinje> zivotinje = new ArrayList<Zivotinje>();
        ArrayList<Zivotinje> zivotinjeLista = new ArrayList<Zivotinje>();

        zivotinje = createZivotinjeList();


        for (Zivotinje ziv : zivotinje) {

            if (ziv.mkey == zivotinjeMenu) {
                zivotinjeLista.add(ziv);
            }
        }
        return zivotinjeLista;
    }

}
```

This is adapter, I guess I need to handle problems in onbindviewholder method but I do not know how:

```
package com.example.android.animalsoundsforchildren;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class ZivotinjeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_zivotinje, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        Zivotinje zivotinjeIme = mZivotinje.get(position);

        // Set item views based on the data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_name());

        //THIS IS WHERE I HANDALE IMAGE VIEW
        ImageView slika_source = viewHolder.imageView;
        slika_source.setImageResource(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_slika());


        viewHolder.setItem(mZivotinje.get(position));



    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mZivotinje.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView nameTextView;
        private Zivotinje mItem;



        public void setItem(Zivotinje item) {
            this.mItem = item;
        }



        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zivotinjaIme_id);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slika_id);







            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), mItem.getmSound());
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private List<Zivotinje> mZivotinje;

    public ZivotinjeAdapter(List<Zivotinje> animals) {
        mZivotinje = animals;
    }
}
```

Comment: ***public static ArrayList<Zivotinje> createZivotinjeList(){***
and   ***public static ArrayList<Zivotinje> createZivotinjeListPero(String zivotinjeMenu) {***
Try Call it in OnCreate in MainActivity.class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Image loading Library to load the images ,

your getting the OOM because of the resolution of the images.

there are many image loading libraries but I prefer [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). its better than others in many ways,

It will solve your issue of OOM

Here is the usage

```
 ImageView slika_source = viewHolder.imageView;
 Glide.with(mContext)
            .load((Integer) zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_slika())                
            .into(slika_source);
```

Comment: i will try to learn how to do this. Im not pro with android, just start recently. Hope it will not be hard.

Comment: i just do all this, i import library. It is little bit better now. This time i can scroll down but when i go to scroll back it crash again. This is what i done in oncreateview method

Comment: Its working now, i did not put your code in right way. THANK YOU FOR THIS

Answer (score 3):

Mostly while working with loading of lots of bitmaps(images) try to use third party tools/libraries because they are working on basis of proper memory management, memory clearing n all concepts ...which are very difficult tasks.

try to use ...

1). Universal Image Loader

2). Picasso(official Link : http://square.github.io/picasso/)

3). Glide(Github Link : https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

and with this all things don't forget to add permission in manifest file of your project...

android:hardwareAccelerated="true" and  android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `android:largeHeap="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: Thank you. I just try that and app still get crashed

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code

```
mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(3);
```